# Click events not working on tabs

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I have the following jsx code that is not working with mouseclicks:

```
import React from 'react';
import Tabs from 'material-ui/lib/tabs/tabs';
import Tab from 'material-ui/lib/tabs/tab';

const Main = () => (
  <div>
    <Tabs>
      <Tab label="Item One" >
        <div>
          <h2 >Tab One</h2>
          <p>
            This is an example tab.
          </p>
          <p>
            You can put any sort of HTML or react component in here.
            It even keeps the component state!
          </p>
        </div>
      </Tab>
      <Tab label="Item Two" >
        <div>
          <h2 >Tab Two</h2>
          <p>
            This is another example tab.
          </p>
        </div>
      </Tab>
      <Tab label="onActive" >
        <div>
          <h2>Tab Three</h2>
          <p>
            This is a third example tab.
          </p>
        </div>
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render((
  <Main />
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

It just flat-out is not working. I'm really confused because selecting the tabs with the keyboard works, but not with the mouse. I checked all of the deps, they seem to be fine. Almost the exact same code works in the examples. I've tried to set up a jsfiddle, but I haven't found a hosted source of material-ui to use.

Any idea what is causing this?

**versions**

react@0.14.7
material-ui@0.14.4
react-tap-event-plugin@0.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the Tabs component relies completely upon react-tap-events to trigger the onChange event with no backwards compatibility with simple clicks.

Make sure you do this:

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Comment: I have the same issue even though I have injected the plugin as shown above.

Comment: Update: Updating to "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0" solved it for me.